# Which Ubuntu realese should I pick?

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, 13.10

I have a relatively old pc (5 years old) running on vista. 
I got fed-up with vista and I am not quite convinced with windows 8. I seriously considering to switch to Ubuntu. Being quite new to the Linux/Ubuntu world I am not sure which is the best release for me. Shall I go to the latest release (the 13.10)? or shall I go for the latest LTS (the 12.04) release or something in between?
Is it painful later on to upgrade your Ubuntu system?
Please let me know your recommendations.

From System Requirements there should be no problem. My pc seems to have the suggested requirements for all the latest releases.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it all depends on what you're going to be using the PC for.  If it's just everyday general purpose usage, then I'd recommend going for 13.04 (for now) and when the bugs have been fixed in 13.10, moving onward.  The transition between the 2 should be painless.

If however you're setting up a system where you don't want to be making major architectural changes every 6 months, I'd stick with the LTS versions.  You might be missing out on the latest and greatest, but when you switch the machine on in the morning you're more certain to be able to do a full days work :)

Comment: I'd like to expand a little on this answer.  The LTS editions are the most stable.  For someone starting out with a new OS, you *should* develop your competencies in a stable environment before bridging out to the beta/prerelease versions.  Otherwise, bugs in the beta/prerelease editions will frustrate you as you learn and it'll be harder to get support.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 13.10 is coming on `October 17`, and even though its not a LTS version, i recommend you wait for just a few more days for this release